# JSS Tracking API example fetch errors

Tags: jss, tracking

I am trying to use the JSS Tracking API, according to https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/fundamentals/services/tracking, with Sitecore XP 9.1. Following the example code:

```
import { trackingApi } from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-tracking';

const trackingApiOptions = {
  host: config.sitecoreApiHost,
  querystringParams: {
    sc_apikey: config.sitecoreApiKey,
  },
};

trackingApi
  // note the events are an array - batching is supported
  .trackEvent([{ eventId: 'Download' }], trackingApiOptions)
  .then(() => console.log('Page event pushed'))
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

I get the following error in the browser console log:

```
TypeError: fetcher is not a function errors.
```

When I assign the fetcher in the options (using `node-fetch`), I get a server-side error:

```
Exception: System.Web.HttpException
Message: A public action method 'event' was not found on controller 'Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Tracker.Controllers.JssTrackerController'.
Source: System.Web.Mvc
```

and the following CORS error in my browser:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://sitecore/sitecore/api/jss/track/event?sc_apikey=%7B1F33A17A-47FC-44E4-9E72-96833F787ADB%7D' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

The `Event` method in `Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Tracker.Controllers` only supports POST and not GET, but the trackingApi is performing a GET request.

Any clues? What configuration am I missing?

PS. Using plain Javascript and not Typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the client-side CORS error is a false-positive. The actual problem is that the fetcher is performing a GET iso a POST. My fix for it:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

async function myFetcher(url, data) {
    return await fetch(url, {
        method: 'post', 
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        }, 
        body:  JSON.stringify(data)
    });
}

const trackingApiOptions = {
  host: config.sitecoreApiHost,
  querystringParams: {
    sc_apikey: config.sitecoreApiKey,
  },
  fetcher: myFetcher
};

trackingApi.trackEvent(events, trackingApiOptions);
```

Comment: This is the way its done in the styleguide sample as well: https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/b41311b2aa8ed885a4d6d1d3d030da6e3496515b/samples/react/src/components/Styleguide-Tracking/index.js